# ActiveCollab API - No Description on API time-records commands

Tags: activecollab

ActiveCollab v5.13 - The time-record input form on the website has 6 fields **including "description"**. The API documentation has the other 5 but "description" is nowhere to be found in the documentation.

I want to automate time-record data entry but ... no description.

In the API, what is the parameter name of the time record description?

The fields on the input screen:

- Time
- Description
- Job Type
- Date
- Task
- Billable

The fields on the /projects/(number)/time-records command (copied from the API documentation:

```
{  
  "value": 1.5,  
  "user_id": 1,  
  "job_type_id": 1,  
  "record_date": "2014-05-14",  
  "billable_status": 0  
}
```

[API Documentation](https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/projects/elements/time-records/time-records.html)

Answer (score 0):

Descriptions are returned in the API (docs are not up to date). Here's a sample from the call made by the system:

```
billable_status: 1
class: "TimeRecord"
created_by_id: 44
created_on: 1496929240
id: 5275
is_trashed: false
job_type_id: 1
parent_id: 52314
parent_type: "Task"
record_date: 1496880000
summary: ""
trashed_by_id: 0
trashed_on: null
updated_by_id: 44
updated_on: 1496929240
url_path: "/projects/204/time-records/5275"
user_id: 44
value: 1
```

It's `summary` that you are looking for.